# Routing to the same action, sending a param based on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I have a series of urls I'd like to all route to the same action, but have each pass a parameter based on what they are.

Normally, this would be easy. I'd just do something like

```
  url/:matcher => controller#action
```

and I'd have :matcher available.

However, this is at the root level, and I dont feel right about having a route for simply `/:matcher` since that would capture a lot more than I intend.

Is there a way to match, for instance:

```
/myroute => 'controller#action' {param[:route] = 'myroute'}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can set `defaults`:

```
get '/myroute', to: 'controller#action', defaults: { route: 'myroute' }
get '/myotherroute', to: 'controller#action', defaults: { route: 'myotherroute' }
```

This sets a parameter called `route` which will be available under `params[:route]` in your controller.

Check out the [defining defaults](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) section of the routes guide.

Comment: Gah, so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints:

```
get '/:matcher' => 'controller#action', matcher: /myroute/
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I'm going to accept CDub's because it's more to what I was trying to do, but this also works and I appreciate the help :]